# If A and B are two mutually exclusive events with P(A) = 0.2 and P(B) = 0.3, then what is P (A and B(complement))

Tags: probability, statistics

If A and B are two mutually exclusive events with P(A) = 0.2 and P(B) = 0.3, then what is P (A and B(complement))

I thought it would be P(B complement) = 0.7, because it is 1-0.3, and then P (A) = 0.2, so 0.2 * 0.7 = .14 but unfortunately this was incorrect.

Comment: $P(A\cap B^\complement)=P(A)P(B^\complement)$ *only if* $A$ and $B^\complement$ are *independent*.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive means that $\Pr (A \cap B) = 0$.

It should also be easy to deduce that $$\Pr (A) = \Pr (A \cap B) + \Pr (A \cap B^c )$$

I think you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, then $A \subset B^c$,

Hence $P(A \cap B^c) = P(A)$